# Internet connection for third party app in blackberry

Tags: blackberry

Is there any specific settings for third party app using internet connection because when i try lo login,app need network connection and it ask for APN.
I gave APN as "blackberry.net" as given by vodafone but it gives me "tunnel failure error" or "DNS error"
What settings are required so that third party apps can use internet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using "WWW" as access point for Vodafone. if still not proper check out for connection types. or just add ";deviceside=true" at the end of your url.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a programming question.

If you are trying to use a third party app, and you are not able to (tunnel failure) set the apn in your phone in the following way.

> Some third-party applications might require a direct TCP or HTTP connection to the Internet. For example, a stock price application might require a connection to the Internet to retrieve the latest stock prices. The TCP settings might be required for the third-party application to access the Internet.
>
> Note: Contact your wireless service provider to obtain the Access Point Name (APN), user name, and password.
>
> 1. On the Home screen of the BlackBerry smartphone, click Options.
>      Note: Depending on the theme running on your BlackBerry smartphone, you may need to click Settings, then Options.
> 2. Complete one of the following:

1. For BlackBerry® Device Software version 4.1 or later, click Advanced Options > TCP/IP
2. For BlackBerry Device Software version 4.0 or earlier, click TCP/IP.

> 1. Enter the APN, user name, and password obtained from your wireless service provider.
> 2. Press the Menu key and select Save.

This information is from [here](http://btsc.webapps.blackberry.com/btsc/search.do?cmd=displayKC&docType=kc&externalId=KB05327)